# How to define optional parameters for a method using XML-RPC.NET

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

I'm developing a XML-RPC service in C# using the [XML-RPC.NET library](http://xml-rpc.net). The service will be used to expose a forum to Tapatalk users

The Tapatalk API documentation states which methods should be implemented. Sometimes a parameter is specified as optional.

E.g. `get_topic` has 4 parameters: `forum_id`, `start_num`, `last_num` and `mode`

The method is invoked by the Tapatalk app with either all parameters or only the first 3 (so `mode` is omitted).

I defined the methods as follows:

```
[XmlRpcMethod("get_topic"]
public GetTopicResult GetTopic(string forum_id, int? start_num, int? last_num, string mode)
```

When the method is invoked with all 4 parameters specified all goes well. When `mode` is omitted I get the following error: `Request contains too few param elements based on method signature.`

Specifing mode as an optional parameter doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
[XmlRpcMethod("get_topic"]
public GetTopicResult GetTopic(string forum_id, int? start_num, int? last_num, string mode = "")
```

Trying to overload the method results in this error: `Method GetTopic in type Mobiquo has duplicate XmlRpc method name get_topic`

```
[XmlRpcMethod("get_topic"]
public GetTopicResult GetTopic(string forum_id, int? start_num, int? last_num)

[XmlRpcMethod("get_topic"]
public GetTopicResult GetTopic(string forum_id, int? start_num, int? last_num, string mode)
```

Any idea how I specify a parameter as optional?

Niels

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? Justing getting into the world of xml-rpc myself.

http://xml-rpc.net/faq/xmlrpcnetfaq-3-0-0.html#1.15

Comment: I checked out the FAQ first thing, but this is for optional mapping of parameters of a response struct (if I understand it correctly).